# Storing function pointer for later use

Tags: c++, embedded, function-pointers

I've tried to find the answer to this but haven't found anything that works. I'm trying to create a class of static methods so I can pass in a function pointer to `SPI::transmitData()` that I can later call with `SPI::call()`. However, I'm getting an error:

> unresolved symbol SPI::mycallback, first referenced in ./spi.obj

spi.h:

```
#ifndef SPI_H_
#define SPI_H_

#include "msp430g2553.h"

class SPI {
public:
    typedef void (*foo)(void);
    static foo mycallback;

    static void transmitData(unsigned char data, foo callback);
    static void call();
};

#endif /* SPI_H_ */
```

spi.cpp:

```
#include "spi.h"

void SPI::transmitData(unsigned char data, foo callback) {
    mycallback = callback; // causes error
    UCA0TXBUF = data;
}

void SPI::call() {
    //SPI::mycallback();
}
```

I've been trying to fiddle with it and the error goes away when I comment the line I marked. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to instantiate static member before using it:

in spi.cpp

```
SPI::foo SPI::mycallback = NULL;
```

Comment: *facepalm* I tried putting this line into the header and was getting a redefinition error. Thanks, the first day of getting reacquainted with C++ has been rough.

Comment: @ArneMertz Sorry, I tried to accept too soon, it didn't let me, and I promptly forgot. Thanks for the reminder!